# Sequencing consecutive functions and adjust for-loop in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop

Background: the code below picks either a word or an image and displays it in my 'abc' div. It measures the reaction time.

Aim: I want to have the function run only 8 times (not 8 keypresses), record the time for each run regardless the keypress event (i.e. a time of 2000 when no key is pressed), and I want this function run first, and after it has finished I want to run a second function.

I researched the $deferred method and seem to have failed to adopt it. Furthermore, my 8 function runs, are not eight at all, but seem more like 8 simultaneous runs.

So basically I want to run my function 8 times, then run a next function, and record the time from appearance of a stimulus to the next if not interrupted by keypress.

I'm stuck with it for some time now and have probably lost the overview.

```
var reac_arr = [];
var t1;
function firstFunction(){
  var def = $.Deferred();
      for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        $(function cit(){
        var timeout = 0;
        function showNext(){
            t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                var new_word = stim.name;
                $("#abc").text(new_word);
            }
            else {
                var new_img = stim.path;
                $("#abc").empty();
                var prox_img = $('<img id="abcimg">');
                prox_img.attr('src', new_img);
                prox_img.appendTo('#abc');
            }
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                showNext()
            }, 2000);
        }
        $(document).keypress(function(e){
            if ($(e.target).is('input, textarea')) {
                return;
            };
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (e.which === 97 || e.which === 108 || e.which === 32) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                showNext();
                }, 300);
                var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
                var reac_time = t2 - t1;
                reac_arr.push(reac_time);
            }
        });
    });
  };
setTimeout(function() {
def.resolve();
}, 1000);
return def.promise();
}

function secondFunction(){
var def = $.Deferred();
    alert("It works!")
  };
setTimeout(function() {
def.resolve();
}, 1000);
return def.promise();
}

firstFunction().pipe(secondFunction);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems a bit bloated but if I understood correctly all you need is setInterval().

```
var counter = 0;
var ticker = setInterval(myFunction,2000);//Setup a function to run every 2000ms

function myFunction()
{
    //do your thing
    counter++;//
    if(counter==8){
        //on the 8th time run next function...
    }
}

$(document).keypress(function(e){
    clearInterval(ticker);//Stop the ticker on keypress
});
```